# Remove menu to create landing page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've created a Wordpress landing page which currently converts at 14%. I removed sidebar and footer to keep the page less distracting.

I think the page can convert even better if I remove the menu from the top. However when I try to create a custom page template it doesn't work. I cannot remove the header without breaking up the whole layout.

Can anyone point me the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share the link you're working on so I can give a more specific answer?

You can probably do it with CSS. Or you need to use a conditional statement to hide sections within the header.php file - you can't remove the whole file cause that will break your HTML structure.

The conditional would be something like:

```
<?php if (!is_page_template('landing-page.php')) { ?>
   <!-- YOUR HEADER HERE -->
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks tom, here is the link http://bit.ly/Z1ClSe Looking forward to your response.

Comment: You can do this easily with CSS. Add this code to your stylesheet - I'll also explain how it works.

`.page-id-2470 .menu-wrapper { display:none; }`
`.page-id-2470 .main { margin: 20px auto 30px auto; }`

That's just targeting the page ID which is set as a class on the `<body>` element, then hiding the menu wrapper, and pushing the content wrapper down 20px to make it look right visually.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome !!! It worked. Thanks a ton mate. I'll update with any changes in conversion rate.

Comment: No worries! Would be interested to hear if it helped. Also would love it if you could accept my answer if it worked :)

Comment: After 2 weeks, the conversion rate is at 21% compared to 14% before. Very happpy with the change. Next step is to add better content, hopefully that would take it even further.

Comment: Thats a massive jump - interesting to hear that it made that much of a difference - congrats.